# Cocoa crash from non-existant NSViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa

In my mac app I'm presenting a login window (in an NSViewController via a `sheet` segue).  There's an OK button on it, and when I press that I make a network call.  At the end of the network call I do some stuff and then dismiss the sheet.  The sheet does in fact disappear.

Now back on my NSViewController that presented the login window I start scrolling an NSTableView up and down.  I'm getting a CoreAnimation warning about uncommitted CATransaction messages.  Sometimes it causes a crash, sometimes it doesn't.

This is the stack trace I get:

> CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
>   0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8befe69a _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 318
>   1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8befe19a _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 276
>   2   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8bf04719 _ZN2CA5Layer13thread_flags_EPNS_11TransactionE + 37
>   3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8bf04668 _ZN2CA5Layer4markEPNS_11TransactionEjj + 64
>   4   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8bf0612b _ZN2CA5Layer25set_needs_display_in_rectERK6CGRect + 333
>   5   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8bf05fdc -[CALayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 25
>   6   AppKit                              0x00007fff91aff2e8 _NSBackingLayerSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 319
>   7   AppKit                              0x00007fff91aff1a3 -[_NSBackingLayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 61
>   8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8bf05f9d -[CALayer setNeedsDisplay] + 62
>   9   AppKit                              0x00007fff91aff98b -[NSView(NSInternal) _setLayerNeedsDisplayInViewRect:] + 606
>   10  AppKit                              0x00007fff91acd88e NSViewSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 945
>   11  AppKit                              0x00007fff91acd4d6 -[NSView setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 48
>   12  AppKit                              0x00007fff91acd2ed -[NSView setNeedsDisplay:] + 81
>   13  AppKit                              0x00007fff91e48905 -[NSProgressIndicator setDoubleValue:] + 338
>   14  Digital Traffic System              0x0000000100063fba _TFFFC22Digital_Traffic_System19LoginViewControllerP33_5EDE918279C9F0B1F3EE7B966507D60715okButtonPressedFCSo8NSButtonT_U_FGSqPs9AnyObject__T_U_FTSSSi_T_ + 266
>   15  Digital Traffic System              0x0000000100064282 _TTRXFo_oSSdSi_dT__XFo_iTSSSi__iT__ + 66

Line 14 shows my "okButtonPressed" method from the LoginViewController, and then on line 13 I see it talking about my NSProgressIndicator trying to have a value set.  It shouldn't even exist at this point :(

Here's what that method looks like:

```swift
final class LoginViewController: NSViewController, HasMOC {
    @IBOutlet private weak var progressBar: NSProgressIndicator!

    @IBAction private func okButtonPressed(sender: NSButton) {
        sender.enabled = false

        commitEditing()

        // Webserver uses Alamofire to make async web calls.
        Webserver.sharedInstance.startupData {
            [unowned self] data in

            defer { sender.enabled = true }

            guard let json = data as? [[[String : AnyObject]]] else {
                NSAlert.okWithMessage("Failed to download data from web server.")
                return
            }

            self.progressBar.hidden = false

            DataImporter.importData(json, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext,
                onType: {
                    [weak self] str, max in
                    self?.progressBar.doubleValue = 0
                    self?.progressBar.maxValue = Double(max)
                    self?.progressText.stringValue = str
                }, onEntity:  {
                    [weak self] in
                    self?.progressBar.incrementBy(1)
                }, onComplete: {
                    [weak self] in
                    (NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).showHideReportMenu()

                    self?.onLoginSuccessful?()

                    self?.dismissController(nil)
            })
        }
}
```

I use unowned in the initial block because this window can't disappear unless the web call has returned.  There's no button to make it go away manually.

Comment: I just added print statements in onType, onEntity and onComplete.  The onComplete gets call and the sheet goes away.  When I start scrolling the table, and get the stack trace, it does NOT re-print any of those three messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service callbacks are executed on non-UI thread and you try to update UI elements.

You should move those onto Main Queue, i.e.:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        [unowned self] in
        //Your code changing UI elements, kicking animations .e.t.c
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the data importer was running in a different context.